# Pathfinding: Fill a maze with convex hulls

Tags: c#, graph-theory, path-finding, convex-hull

I'm trying to make a A* pathfinder script :

My script fills the maze with a grid of squares,
It then goes through each rectangle and if that rectangle is:
touching a square + with the same dimension along the edge they touch, has the same movment cost - then they will merge.
This step is repeated and will fill the maze with larger rectangles speeding up the pathfinding process.

[image]

But it does not fill to the edges of the walls, and I would prefer an algorithm that fill the maze with convex hulls instead of being limited to rectangles. Is there a name for an algorithm like that?

Comment: " the same dimension along the edge they touch"  What does this mean?

Comment: Like if two rectangles are touching left to right and they are the same height they can merge, but if they different heights then they cannot merge as that would not be a convex shape

Comment: You might want to take a look at [A* variations](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Variations.html). Some mentions preprocessing the graph into a smaller sets of significant nodes, like corners and doorways etc.

Comment: There are likely greedy methods for creating convex hulls. Maybe just repeatedly merge neighboring nodes if the result is convex. But if you aim for some kind of "optimal" solution you might need to do more research.

Comment: Research suggestion: Voronoi diagrams.  Start from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: Research suggestion #2: Flood fill algorithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill